# Mini Displayport out to USB-C Monitor (4K)

Tags: monitors, video-adapters, 4k

I have a 4k monitor which has both a usb-c input and a HDMI input. However, the HDMI input does not support 4k, only the USB-C does.

I am using the Macbook Pro 2015 13-inch Retina which has 2 Mini Displayports that should be able to output 4K.

There are USB-C to Mini Displayport adapters out there but they seem to be intended to be used from USB-C output to Mini Displayport monitor and not the way I would need it.

More information about the monitor can be found here (I also got the Hub):
https://cforcedesign.com/collections/frontpage/products/cf015c-4k-ultra-slim-portable-display

Answer (score 2):

Going from Displayport to USB-C does not really work because while USB-C contains Displayport, the same is not true in reverse.

However, the ports on the Macbook Pro 2015 are techinically Thunderbolt 2, so what you are looking for boils down to this question you can find on the Apple Stackexchange. [Is Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3 possible?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278078/is-thunderbolt-2-to-thunderbolt-3-type-c-possible)

[This adapter](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207266) is bidirectional. So you can use it to do what you are asking, **if the CForce hub supports full Thunderbolt 3**. If it does not, you may be able to find a different hub that will allow you to make the conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check if the hub supports it and then try it out. Would be really great if I could use the monitor finally in 4k resolution.